# UTF8 in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, utf-8

I am trying to import data from xls to mysql via php. I am facing issue in save UTF-8 text via it. I am getting it saved as **???????.** My database table structure is utf8_general_ci as well my php code is like below

```html
 <?php 
    $con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'myuser', 'mypass', 'mydb');


    if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
    {
    mysqli_query($con,'SET character_set_results=utf8');
    mysqli_query($con,'SET names=utf8');
    mysqli_query($con,'SET character_set_client=utf8');
    mysqli_query($con,'SET character_set_connection=utf8');
    mysqli_query($con,'SET character_set_results=utf8');
    mysqli_query($con,'SET collation_connection=utf8_general_ci');
    $file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $handle = fopen($file, "r");
    $i = 0;
    while(($filesop = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== false)
    { 
    $option1 = $filesop[0];
    $option2 = $filesop[1];
    $option3 = $filesop[2];
    $option4 = $filesop[3];
    $correctans = $filesop[4];
    $question_text = $filesop[5];
    $cat_id = $filesop[6];
    $sub_cat_id = $filesop[7];
    $level_id = $filesop[8];
    $quesimage = $filesop[9];

    $sql = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT IGNORE INTO questions (option1, option2,option3,option4,correctans,question_text,cat_id,sub_cat_id,level_id,quesimage) VALUES ('".$option1."','".$option2."','".$option3."','".$option4."','".$correctans."','".$question_text."','".$cat_id."','".$sub_cat_id."','".$level_id."','".$quesimage."')");
    $i = $i + 1;
     
    }
    //echo $sql;
    if($sql)
    {
    echo "You database has imported successfully. You have inserted ". $i ." records";
    }
    else
    {
    echo "Sorry!";
    }

    }
     
    ?>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Import Questions</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Upload Excel File : <input type="file" name="file" /><br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload" />
    </form> 
    </body>
    </html>
```

its working fine with English Text but getting issue in **Hindi or Gujarati Text.** How can I solve it ?

Thanks

Comment: Please try to  make the charset of the database: utf8_unicode_ci and ENGINE=InnoDB

Comment: what's encoding use your `xls` file?

Comment: @Federkun How can I know it ? Thanks

Comment: Let's see the hex for something.  Do something like `echo $question_text, bin2hex($question_text);`  (or some column that is giving you trouble)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that when using `fgetcsv()` function for reading data the `locale` setting is taken into account. If `LANG` is e.g. `en_US.UTF-8`, files in one-byte encoding are read wrong by this function.

You can try another thing - to convert your `.csv` document on-the-fly (change the `UCS-2` with the your file encoding):

```
function parse_csv($filename) {
    if (($handle != fopen($filename, "r"))) return false;
    while (($cols = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, "\t")) !== FALSE) {
        foreach( $cols as $key => $value ) {
            $cols[$key] = trim( $cols[$key] );
            $cols[$key] = iconv('UCS-2', 'UTF-8', $cols[$key]."\0") ;
            $cols[$key] = str_replace('""', '"', $cols[$key]);
            $cols[$key] = preg_replace("/^\"(.*)\"$/sim", "$1", $cols[$key]);
        }
        echo var_dump($cols); //This will display an array of your data
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please explain little that how can I use this function with my code ? Thanks

Comment: I would expect 'UCS-2' to be wrong.  But without knowing what generated the incoming code, we cannot say what would be right.

Comment: You should _not_ have to convert the incoming text; MySQL can convert almost any encoding.

Answer (score 0):

Using the same idea of the previous post, with a little modification:

```
function global_client_charset($charset){
if(!isset($charset)){
    $user_agent = strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
    if(strrpos($user_agent,"linux")){
    $GLOBALS["CHARSET"] = "UTF-8";
    }else if(strrpos($user_agent,"windows")){
    $GLOBALS["CHARSET"] = "ISO-8859-1";
    }
}else{
        $GLOBALS["CHARSET"] = $charset;
}       
}

function toUTF8($data){
    if($GLOBALS["CHARSET"] === "ISO-8859-1"){
        return iconv("ISO-8859-1", "UTF-8", trim($data));
    }else if($GLOBALS["CHARSET"] === "UTF-8"){
       return trim($data);
    }else{
       return trim($data);
    }
}

if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
$file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$handle = fopen($file, "r");
$i = 0;

//do you know the charset you are receiving ??
//global_client_charset("ISO-8859-1");
global_client_charset();

while(($filesop = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== false)
{   
    $option1 = $filesop[0];
    $option2 = $filesop[1];
    $option3 = $filesop[2];
    $option4 = $filesop[3];
    $correctans = $filesop[4];
    $question_text = $filesop[5];
    $cat_id = $filesop[6];
    $sub_cat_id = $filesop[7];
    $level_id = $filesop[8];
    $quesimage = $filesop[9];


    $query = "INSERT IGNORE INTO questions (option1, option2,option3,option4,correctans,question_text,cat_id,sub_cat_id,level_id,quesimage) VALUES ('".
    $option1."','".$option2."','".$option3."','".$option4."','".$correctans."','".$question_text."','".
    $cat_id."','".$sub_cat_id."','".$level_id."','".$quesimage."')"; 

    //echo toUTF8($query); die();
    $sql = mysqli_query($con,toUTF8($query));
    $i = $i + 1;        
}

if($sql)
{
    echo "You database has imported successfully. You have inserted ". $i ." records";
}
else
{
    echo "Sorry!";
}
}
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Import Questions</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
Upload Excel File : <input type="file" name="file" /><br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload" />
</form> 
</body>
</html>
```